# How do I create a DataTable, then add rows to it?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I've tried creating a `DataTable` and adding rows to it like this:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.clear();
 dt.Columns.Add("Name");
 dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
```

How do I see the structure of `DataTable`?

Now I want to add *ravi* for `Name` and *500* for `Marks`. How can I do this?

Comment: @Cute. Just a comment- if you are using .NET 3.5 you should really see what LINQ to SQL offers. If you do decide to go down the DataTable/DataSet route at least look in to creating DataTables that are strongly typed.

Answer (score 321):

Here's the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
DataRow _ravi = dt.NewRow();
_ravi["Name"] = "ravi";
_ravi["Marks"] = "500";
dt.Rows.Add(_ravi);
```

To see the structure, or rather I'd rephrase it as schema, you can export it to an XML file by doing the following.

To export only the schema/structure, do:

```
dt.WriteXMLSchema("dtSchemaOrStructure.xml");
```

Additionally, you can also export your data:

```
dt.WriteXML("dtDataxml");
```

Comment: Don't forget to call dt.AcceptChanges() in case you use DataView with filter other than CurrentRows.

Comment: @phoenix: I just wanted the question asker to happily relate with my answer.

Comment: @Salamander2007 : It seems just an in memory datatable created at runtime, so we dnt need to call AcceptChanges()

Comment: I don't think there is a method on DataTable (dt) called `NewDataRow`. There is, however, a `NewRow` method, but as this is not initially "attached" to the table, you still have to add it to the table, e.g., `var dr = dt.NewRow(); dt.Rows.Add(dr);`

Comment: DataTable is disposable so to avoid memory leaks you should wrap it in using block.

Comment: .clear is seems mandatory, it won't work for me without clear.

Answer (score 88):

**Create DataTable:**

```
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable(); // 1
DataTable MyTableByName = new DataTable("MyTableName"); // 2
```

**Add column to table:**

```
 MyTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
 MyTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
```

**Add row to DataTable method 1:**

```
DataRow row = MyTable.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 1;
row["Name"] = "John";
MyTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

**Add row to DataTable method 2:**

```
MyTable.Rows.Add(2, "Ivan");
```

**Add row to DataTable method 3 (Add row from another table by same structure):**

```
MyTable.ImportRow(MyTableByName.Rows[0]);
```

**Add row to DataTable method 4 (Add row from another table):**

```
MyTable.Rows.Add(MyTable2.Rows[0]["Id"], MyTable2.Rows[0]["Name"]);
```

**Add row to DataTable method 5 (Insert row at an index):**

```
MyTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, 8);
```

Comment: When adding columns to the DataTable, must you call `MyTable.Columns.Add()' for each column, or can you list all of your columns inside of one .Add() method?

Comment: @KyleVassella one call of ```MyTable.Columns.Add()``` is enough.

Answer (score 84):

You can also pass in an object array as well, like so:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
object[] o = { "Ravi", 500 };
dt.Rows.Add(o);
```

Or even:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ravi", 500 });
```

Comment: Another alternative on this is to note the `Add` method shown above has an overload with variable number of params, so you could shorten this to `dt.Rows.Add("Ravi", 500);` and would work the same. One big warning with either of these approaches: you must supply these parameters in exact same order as the columns were defined, else you'll get an error. (So use with caution!)

Answer (score 39):

```
// Create a DataTable and add two Columns to it
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Age",typeof(int));

// Create a DataRow, add Name and Age data, and add to the DataTable
DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"]="Mohammad"; // or dr[0]="Mohammad";
dr["Age"]=24; // or dr[1]=24;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

// Create another DataRow, add Name and Age data, and add to the DataTable
dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"]="Shahnawaz"; // or dr[0]="Shahnawaz";
dr["Age"]=24; // or dr[1]=24;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

// DataBind to your UI control, if necessary (a GridView, in this example)
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 32):

To add a row:

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Name"] = "Ravi";
row["Marks"] = 500;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

To see the structure:

```
Table.Columns
```

Answer (score 25):

You can add Row in a single line

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can write **one liner** using [DataRow.Add(params object[] values)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of four lines.

```
dt.Rows.Add("Ravi", "500");
```

As you create new `DataTable` object, there seems *no* need to `Clear` `DataTable` in very next statement. You can also use `DataTable.Columns.AddRange` to add columns with on statement. Complete code would be.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Marks") });     
dt.Rows.Add("Ravi", "500");
```

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to create a DtaTable as of now

```
DataTable table = new DataTable
{
    Columns = {
        "Name", // typeof(string) is implied
        {"Marks", typeof(int)}
    },
    TableName = "MarksTable" //optional
};
table.Rows.Add("ravi", 500);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
Datacolumn Name = new DataColumn("Name");
Name.DataType= typeoff(string);
Name.AllowDBNull=false; //set as null or not the default is true i.e null
Name.MaxLength=20; //sets the length the default is -1 which is max(no limit)
dt.Columns.Add(Name);
Datacolumn Age = new DataColumn("Age", typeoff(int));`

dt.Columns.Add(Age);

DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();

dr["Name"]="Mohammad Adem"; // or dr[0]="Mohammad Adem";
dr["Age"]=33; // or dr[1]=33;
dt.add.rows(dr);
dr=dt.NewRow();

dr["Name"]="Zahara"; // or dr[0]="Zahara";
dr["Age"]=22; // or dr[1]=22;
dt.rows.add(dr);
Gv.DataSource=dt;
Gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)); 

dt.Columns.Add(Name);
DataColumn Age = new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int));`

dt.Columns.Add(Age);

DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();

dr["Name"]="Kavitha Reddy"; 
dr["Age"]=24; 
dt.add.Rows(dr);
dr=dt.NewRow();

dr["Name"]="Kiran Reddy";
dr["Age"]=23; 
dt.Rows.add(dr);
Gv.DataSource=dt;
Gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to add datarows to your datatable for this.

```
// Creates a new DataRow with the same schema as the table.
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

// Fill the values
dr["Name"] = "Name";
dr["Marks"] = "Marks";

// Add the row to the rows collection
dt.Rows.Add ( dr );
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers.

If you control the structure of the DataTable there is a shortcut for adding rows:

// Assume you have a data table defined as in your example named dt
dt.Rows.Add("Name", "Marks");

The DataRowCollection.Add() method has an overload that takes a param array of objects. This method lets you pass as many values as needed, but they must be in the same order as the columns are defined in the table.

So while this is a convenient way to add row data, it can be risky to use. If the table structure changes your code will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: How do create a DataTable in C#?

**Answer 1:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // DataTable created

// Add columns in your DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
```

***Note:*** There is no need to `Clear()` the `DataTable` after creating it.

> Question 2: How to add row(s)?

**Answer 2:** Add one row:

```
dt.Rows.Add("Ravi","500");
```

Add multiple rows: use `ForEach` loop

```
DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)Session["CartData"]; // This DataTable contains multiple records
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr["Name"], dr["Marks"]);
}
```