# How to dynamically fill a row in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

```
DataTable exportTable = new DataTable();

exportTable.Columns.Add("Place", typeof(string));
exportTable.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));

foreach (var time in timeList)
{
    exportTable.Columns.Add(time, typeof(string)); 
}

exportTable.Rows.Add("New York", 1/1/2015, ?, ?, ?, ...);
```

How can I dynamically fill a row in a DataTable?

Comment: You need to create a `DataRow` to insert. [An example may be seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042618/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-c-sharp-and-how-to-add-rows)

Comment: From what source do you want to fill the row?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
    DataTable ItemTable = new DataTable("MyTable");
    ItemTable.Columns.Add("ID"      , typeof(int   ));
    ItemTable.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int   ));
    ItemTable.Columns.Add("Name"    , typeof(String));


    // add some test data
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0,-1, "Bill Gates"    });
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 0, "Steve Ballmer" });
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1, "Mary Smith"    });
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 0, "Paul Allen"    });
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2, "Ahmed Jones"   });
    ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2, "Wing Lee"      }
);
```