# Convert an array to a DataTable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

How to convert one dimensional `Array` to the `DataTable`?

For Example: we have following multiple `Arrays` with different lengths and want to convert to `Datatable`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("MiddelName");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
dt.Columns.Add("City");
dt.Columns.Add("State");
dt.Columns.Add("Zip");

string[] strArray = "naveen, kumar, katara, , CA, 92606".Split(Char.Parse(","));
string[] strArray1 = "Aadhya, , Adtya, Irvine, CA, 98623".Split(Char.Parse(","));
string[] strArray2 = "xyz, , mno".Split(Char.Parse(","));

var convertedTable = GetDataTable(strArray, dt);
convertedTable = GetDataTable(strArray1, dt);

//Final output as Converted table:
convertedTable = GetDataTable(strArray2, dt);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a DataTable in C# and how to add rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042618/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-c-sharp-and-how-to-add-rows)

Comment: there is an easier way to do this but doing it I can post you an example of how to do this however in my opinion I think that you should be using a `List<object>` to initialize your row data.. please let me know if you would like to see an example on how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

you could manually add the rows

```
        dt.Rows.Add(strArray[0], strArray[1], strArray[2], strArray[3], strArray[4], strArray[5]);
        dt.Rows.Add(strArray1[0], strArray1[1], strArray1[2], strArray1[3], strArray1[4], strArray1[5]);
        dt.Rows.Add(strArray2[0], strArray2[1]);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```