# Not getting count for datatable object

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to check if there exist any record in the query.

So what I tried is

```
 DataTable dtmkeylength = new DataTable("select count(lease_no) from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey = " + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "");

        if (dtmkeylength.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            HidMode.Value = "M";
            HidMKey.Value = dtmkeylength.Rows[0]["Mkey"].ToString();
        }
```

The below datatable object has count of `2` records into the database, but still it is not going inside *IF* condition.

WHY ?

Comment: Seems like this needs a debug, try to debug the `dtmkeylength` instance and see if there is actually any data retrieved, I suspect that the select statement didn't return any rows

Comment: By calling `new DataTable("select count(lease_no) from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey = " + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "");` you just create `DataTable` with name `select count(lease_no) from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey = + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();`

Comment: @SeM: so what shd I do to get the record in datatable object ?

Comment: read [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder) article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your query add the "as NNN" thing:

```
...select count(lease_no) as result...
```

so you can reference it by name.

Then, when you query, you can type:

```
dtmkeylength.Rows[0]["result"]
```

I hope that fixes it for you :)

EDIT

```
var userId = Request.QueryString["UserId"];

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)){
  throw new Exception("No UserID = no fun!");
}

DataTable dtmkeylength = new DataTable("select count(lease_no) from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey =" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "");

        if (dtmkeylength.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            HidMode.Value = "M";
            HidMKey.Value = dtmkeylength.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I think `dtmkeylength.Rows.Count` should contain something, regardless of the column alias you suggested, right?

Comment: Row count should be 1, since he's selecting a count without grouping, so yeah, that's right. I guess he could also just address column 0 instead of using the column alias. Not as verbose, but still does the trick

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it should contain 1 row with value of 0 at least

Comment: @PedroG.Dias: can you update your answer totally. As  I am confused how to write it ?

Comment: Try this: HidMKey.Value = dtmkeylength.Rows[0][0].ToString();

Comment: sorry, didn't got u. it is not related to getting record into the datatable. Kindly update your answer.Please

Comment: Well then it must be your query, check the userId against the table to see if it exists. Try executing the query in your favourite SQL editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach is to use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx), since you are using only the count.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    String sql = "select count(lease_no) from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey = @mkey";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mkey", (int) Request.QueryString["userid"]);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int rowCount = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (rowCount  > 0)
        {
            HidMode.Value = "M";
            HidMKey.Value = dtmkeylength.Rows[0]["Mkey"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Also note the parameterized query - `@mkey` is provided as a parameter and string concatenation is not used (this may lead to Sql Injection)

Comment: how to pass mkey as a parameter ? as it takes when the user is logged

Comment: You can have an extra `if` condition to treat unlogged user case. What is your code supposed to do when the user is not logged in?

Comment: it will redirect to an error page, if the user is not logged in. So can u update the code if user is unlogged...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string param = "VINET";//your param here
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
            using(SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //modify your command on below line
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(OrderId) from Orders where CustomerID='" + param + "'");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //do other staff
                }
            }
        }
```

*Please follow commented lines

**Edit**
Below is a debug screen shot of your way of populating data table. As you can see, dt is detecting the command as table name and NOT as command.
[image]

Comment: thanks, but it would be great if you let me know in my question only. I have also created and it is working thier

Comment: The way you are placing your select command in DataTable constructor, is not write because even though you are placing a command string, the constructor is detecting it as TABLE NAME (see DataTable's constructor overload). As a result, your datatable was never populated and as expected, it does not going inside IF condition

Answer (score 0):

It WILL always return rows even if the row count is zero.

try

```
int number = dtmkeylength.Rows[0].Field<int>(0);

if (number > 0)
{
...
}
```

Comment: tried like this .`DataTable dtmkeylength = new DataTable("select count(lease_no) as result from XXACL_PROSPECTIVE_DATA_SAVE where mkey =" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "");

            int number = Convert.ToInt32(dtmkeylength.Rows[0]["result"]);` getting error as **There is no row at position 0.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for `DataTable` that takes a select statement, thats why it is empty, nothing selected yet!

**The available constructor overloads available are the below three:**

```
System.Data.DataTable dtmkeylength = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Or

```
System.Data.DataTable dtmkeylength = new System.Data.DataTable("TableName);
```

Or

```
System.Data.DataTable dtmkeylength = new System.Data.DataTable("TableName", "tableNameSpace");
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042618/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-c-sharp-and-how-to-add-rows) and [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) example of how to use a `DataTable`