# How do I add a ListBox item to a DataGridView column header

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listboxitem

```cs
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count;)
{
  DT.Columns.AddRange(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
}  

dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
```

How can I add the items from the `ListBox` to the `DataTable` columns header in C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a DataTable in C# and how to add rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042618/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-c-sharp-and-how-to-add-rows)

Comment: `DT.Columns.Add(listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[i]));`. Your loop is missing `i++`, so `i` never increases and you end up adding a Column with the same name (unless it's a typo, that is).

Comment: i use this command it can now increase and decrease if the listbox item have change, but it can't add the data type on the each column(DT.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn(listBox1.Items[i].ToString())});)