# Binding an array of objects to DataGridView control

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datasource, datagridviewcolumn

I have an array of base class `Product` that contains objects of derived classes `Medication` and `Parapharmaceutical`.

In a DataGridView control, I am trying to display all the fields (fields of the base class that are in common and also the specific fields of each derived class).

`dataGridView1.DataSource = ArrayOfProducts;`

`dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;`

`dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Reference";`

`...`

Now the question is how to bind the properties of the array objects to the columns (the objects are of a different type) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want to accomplish here, but it sounds like what you're needing is to set up your "ArrayOfProducts" as a **DataTable** in order to control the association of your data with the correct columns and datatypes.  Does that help?

Comment: Yep, how can I accomplish that please ?

Comment: Do you know the contents of your array?  The answer to this thread has an simple example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042618/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-c-sharp-and-how-to-add-rows